# Calculate coordinates with better precision in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, precision

I'm using the geometry calculator to get the geographic coordinates of a point shapefile.
However when I run it, it calculates the coordinates with 4 decimal points, regardless I've chosen double an increase the precision on the field definition..

I need the coordinates with at least 8 decimal points.

Can someone offer advice?

Comment: Hi Astrid, welcome to GIS.SE. From memory Shapefiles store coordinates as doubles (IEEEE 32 bit floating point) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_.28.shp.29, depending on how many numbers are before the decimal you may not be able to get more than 8 decimal places. Why do you need to get coordinates to the nearest nanometre?

Comment: Hi, thank you! ... I need more than 4 that is what I'm getting at the moment.. I'm working in geographic coordinates and 4 decimal is not representative enough for some points that are so close to each other.. I don't want to project them because I'm using those points to create a kriggin surface in R and I know reprojecting that raster back might result in inaccurate location. Thanks!!

Comment: Make sure that you're seeing all possible digits. Right click the field and select properties. Click Numeric button to access how many digits should display. When I do it, the default is 6 digits. Does the data have a defined coordinate reference system? If not, try defining it with the appropriate geographic coordinate reference system.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson OP mentioned geographic so I assume latitude-longitude. So 8 digits is closer to mm.

Comment: @mkennedy thank you, if I do that I can see more decimal points, but with zeros or 9999 following, so basically it keeps the 4 decimal point precision. and yes it has defined the right geographic coordinate system

Comment: Then that may be all that's actually stored in the geometry values, unfortunately.

Comment: Where did the data come from? Were they originally recorded to sufficient decimals? Floating point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point isn't a precise storage format so it's not uncommon to see .00000000001 or .9999999999 at the end of the numbers, that does not mean those numbers were entered - it's just the imprecision of the numeric format.

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson -- *double precision* is [IEEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institute_of_Electrical_and_Electronics_Engineers) 64-bit storage (53 bit mantissa)

Comment: @AstridV Does the shapefile have a .shp.xml?  At what scale were the coordinates captured? It sounds like you have 1:10m data.  Data which is *accurate* to 1mm is a good deal rarer than data which is *precise* to 1mm.

Comment: it's actually 1:20k, there few points that are very close to each other and with a 4 decimal points prediction seem to be same location..and when I'm running my geostatistical analysis I have problems because of co-located data! but it's ok, I can use autoCADmap to get the location.. ArcGIS might calculate 4dec places by default!

Comment: @Vince, yeh 64... There's a discussion about it here http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=986&t=234634; IEEE has been around for a long time and has defined floating points from 16 to 128 bits. That's definitely enough precision to record UTM coordinates to the mm; any more refinement on that would be generally unnecessary.

Comment: An 8-byte float pair is enough to store UTM coordinates to the Angstrom, and decimal degrees coordinates submillimeter, though it's rare that geodata is accurate to decimeter scale, so many of those digits are just wasted storage.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @MIchaelMiles-Stimson:

> There's a discussion about it here
>   http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=986&t=234634; IEEE has been
>   around for a long time and has defined floating points from 16 to 128
>   bits. That's definitely enough precision to record UTM coordinates to
>   the mm; any more refinement on that would be generally unnecessary.

and by @Vince:

> An 8-byte float pair is enough to store UTM coordinates to the
>   Angstrom, and decimal degrees coordinates submillimeter, though it's
>   rare that geodata is accurate to decimeter scale, so many of those
>   digits are just wasted storage.